# Gridview is not binding after update

Tags: vb.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a gridview with edit/update command buttons.  I am using a dropdown menu to set the selectcommand for the gridview datasource (ds2) as shown below.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Try
 If ddFilter.SelectedValue = "Title" Then ds2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [contentStore] WHERE ([Title] LIKE '%' + @Title + '%') order by [Title] asc"
 If ddFilter.SelectedValue = "URL" Then ds2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [contentStore] WHERE ([URL] LIKE '%' + @Title + '%') order by [URL] asc"
 If ddFilter.SelectedValue = "ID" Then ds2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [contentStore] WHERE ([ID] LIKE '%' + @Title + '%') order by [ID] asc"
 GridView1.DataBind()
Catch ex As Exception
 lblFilter.Text = "<h3>Filter Issue</h3>" & ex.ToString
 End Try
End Sub
```

The trouble is when I use the edit/update combination the record is updated properly however the gridview doesn't bind itself again.  If I press the button again the gridview is rebound showing the updated data as expected.

My question is how can I get the Gridview to bind by itself after update

Comment: Post your code for the edit/update commands.

Comment: Did you try rebinding at the end of the `row_command` event handler?

Answer (score 1):

Well without seeing your code, my guess is you need to duplicate the logic in your button click handler in the command logic so that the SQL to execute and bind the grid happens again, like this:

```
Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "Edit" Then
        ' Do logic here

        If ddFilter.SelectedValue = "Title" Then 
            ds2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [contentStore] WHERE ([Title] LIKE '%' + @Title + '%') order by [Title] asc"
        End If

        If ddFilter.SelectedValue = "URL" Then 
            ds2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [contentStore] WHERE ([URL] LIKE '%' + @Title + '%') order by [URL] asc"
        End If

        If ddFilter.SelectedValue = "ID" Then 
            ds2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [contentStore] WHERE ([ID] LIKE '%' + @Title + '%') order by [ID] asc"
        End If

        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```